# Prove a matrix satisfying a norm inequality is invertible.

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Given $\|AB-I \|<1$, for any natural matrix norm, prove the matrices $A$ , $B$ and $AB$ are invertible.

Comment: It would be better if you provided us with your insights on the question, namely what you tried doing and why it failed.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to show that $AB$ is invertible, because if $A$ or $B$ aren't of full rank, than $AB$ isn't of full rank, too (why?).

Suppose $AB$ isn't invertible, than $AB$ isn't injective (why?) and so there's a $x$ with $\|x\|=1$ and $ABx=0$. So we get

$$\|AB-I\|=\sup_{\|y\|=1}\|(AB-I)y\|\geq \|ABx-x\|=\|x\|=1$$

a contradiction

Comment: Thank you, i still can't see why $sup_{\| y \| = 1} \| (AB - I)y \|  \geq  \|ABx-x \|$

Comment: Do you know what $sup$ means?